# Monero and ASIC miner

Tags: asic-development

Would it be possible to convert Bitcoin ASIC miner from BTC to Monero(XMR)?

For instance, convert the Titan BTC dragon miner firmware to mine Monero : http://titanminer.com/?product=lketc-dragon-miner-bitcoin-asic-1-5ths-sha-256

Would it work in theory the Monero P2P network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not at all. Bitcoin ASICs are designed with the singular purpose of performing Sha-256 hashing - it's literally written in the silicon. Monero uses the Cryptonight hash function which makes use of AES encryption and several hashing algorithms, Keccak, Blake-256, JH-256, Groestl-256, and Skein-256.

Reference: https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt

Comment: You could specify these "several hashing algorithms" to make your answer better.

Comment: Good point. Added.

Comment: so given the current tech available in the market, we can only mine using common retail GPU and CPU? I mean, there is no hardware specific which can mine monero?